# Como anular uma altura atribuida a uma div?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-3

Estou usando bootstrap e esse é o meu css:

```
.painel-altura{
    height: 540px;
}

@media (min-width: 630px) {

}
```

Gostaria de anular essa altura  e deixar ela do tamanho anterior ao de 540px.  Estou tentando usar @media mas não sei como fazer isso! Dentro de cada tag img esta associado uma image, com exatamente 252 X 252 .

```
     <div class="row slideanim">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="panel panel-default text-center painel-altura">
                            <div class="panel-heading bg-cor-panel-blue">
                                <h1>Recicle....</h1>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <img src="../img/icones/recycled.png" class="img-responsive centralizar">
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-footer">
                                <p><strong>xxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxx x x xxxx  xxxx   xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxx  xxxxx  xxx xxx</strong></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>      
                    </div>     
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="panel panel-default text-center">
                            <div class="panel-heading bg-cor-panel-blue">
                                <h1>Substitua o alumínio</h1>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">

                                <img src="../img/icones/container.png" class="img-responsive centralizar">
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-footer">
                                <p><strong>xxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxx x x xxxx  xxxx   xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxx  xxxxx  xxx xxx
                                    xxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxx x x xxxx  xxxx   xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxx  xxxxx  xxx xxxx
                                    xxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxx x x xxxx  xxxx   xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxx  xxxxx  xxx xxx
                                    xxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxx x x xxxx  xxxx   xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxx  xxxxx  xxx xxx
                                    xxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxx x x xxxx  xxxx   xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxx  xxxxx  xxx xxx
                                    </strong></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>      
                    </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Qual tamanho tu quer que ela fique? E quando tu quer ela desse tamanho?

Comment: @ThiagoSantos Quero que ela fique grande quando estiver sendo visualizada no desktop e volte ao normal quando estiver sendo visualizada em mobile!!

Comment: Não entendi, poderia me explicar?

Answer (score 1):

Eu faço da seguinte forma:

```css
div{
height:700px;
width:700px;
border:1px solid black;
}
@media(max-width:480px){
  div{
    height:250px;
    width:250px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>Sua div</div>
```

Então quando dimensão da tela for inferior a `480px` a regra da `media`será aplicada.

Para visualizar o efeito clica no modo página toda e redimensione sua tela.

Qualquer coisa comenta que agente ajusta.